# stop: unknown instance: networking stop/waiting ubuntu server 12.04.3

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am getting the following MSG after restarting networking services

> stop: unknown instance: networking stop/waiting in ubuntu server 12.04.3

What does lt mean? However I am able to Ping my dns and sites. Can I go ahead and install Samba or I might get problems later because of this error. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're seeing, as least as it relates to 12.04 Server, is that the `networking` service is not invoked and kept in a stopped state. I verified this on both my 12.04 servers with the following:

```
sysadmin@ubuntu-server:/$ service networking status
networking stop/waiting
```

However, NetworkManager is running:

```
sysadmin@ubuntu-server:/$ service network-manager status
network-manager start/running, process 1479
```

and both servers are connected to the network, reachable and functioning fine.

Therefore, if you wish to reload a changed configuration file, you should issue

`service network-manager restart`

Verify your changed settings through `ifconfig`. You may install any software you wish unless it requires a static IP address for some reason (very few do).

Comment: thank you for your help. #Sudo service network-manager restart brings "network-manager: unrecognised service". How do I enable this service? When I run rcconf it does not show any service by that name except network-interface which I have enable as well as network-interface-container and network-interface-security. What other steps am I missing/should do. I have however installed one piece of software an it is working perfectly. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: @Given What file did you edit to make the changes to your network config? I will need to edit/delete my answer as I realized `network-manager` is only active if you have a GUI on your system, which Server typically does not unless you've installed one.

Comment: thanks you gave me the clue. Sudo rcconf did not show that network-manager service was there.http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-networking-tips-and-tricks/ showed that there was supposed to be a directory /etc/NetworkManager. My /etc did not have this. So I concluded that network manager was not installed or enable. Despite another site suggesting that in ubuntu it is installed by default I just installed it through apt-get install network-manager. Then rcconf showed network-manager, networking & network-manager status, network-manager status all worked Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed such problem adding to the file `/etc/network/run/ifstate` string

```
eth0=eth0
```

previously file contained only string `lo=lo`.

Also I created file `/etc/network/run/ifup.eth0` with touch and that solved problem,
service networking start/stop started to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Running `/etc/init.d/networking re/start/stop/status` is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces.

You can still make the same using the command:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

It doesn't mean you can't use Internet so feel free to install whatever there is no problem

Comment: Hi Hadi thanks. I have done what you have suggested above but the error persists.

Comment: what is the error please post what did u do and what is the output

Answer (score 0):

If using VMware, Check and make sure under Network Adapter for the guest VM, the Device Status has "Connected" and "Connect at power on" check. The reboot the VM.